# Message level encryption

Tags: security, networking, encryption

I’m trying to implement a message level encryption. Here is the current situation:

We have a mobile app client connects to server via oneway certificate https and we have username/password authentication and secure token for subsequent client to server invocations. So intention of message level encryption is not try to prevent 3rd part sniffing information or stealing client identity, instead to prevent the client user him/her self to something like,

1) Inspect and try to understand server - client protocol
2) Forgery request with other application than our app client

The initial idea is to use symmetric algorithm (DES, AES, or some simpler algorithm, as long as it could not be simply cracked by statistical or mathematical method without knowing the key). And the key is generated from a hash (SHA etc) from a string concatenated from a salt pre-agreed between client and server, and some information server tell client in non-encrypted content (for instance, the first call from client to server happens in non-encrypted context, and server returns a timestamp to client and also remember it for later key generating).

Does this do what I want to do for 1&2? And what is the major vulnerability if any?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly the intention of your message level encryption is not security but obscurity to prevent competitors to connect to your servers?

Comment: The app is a Game, we are trying to prevent bot program connect to server.

Comment: The app is a Game, we are trying to prevent bot program connect to server.

Comment: Obscurity would help. I just realised what I really need something to sign the message. For instance, calculate a HMAC tag and sent to server together with the message payload. The key-gen strategy could use the same as above for encryption.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "secure" solution to what you try to achieve as long as you publish your software, because any key you use for the message level encryption will have to reach your software somehow. Either it is compiled into it, then a dedicated attacker can read it out of the binary, or it is transferred to the running software using the network, then the attacker can emulate the protocol your software is using to get the key.

The best you can hope for is to make it difficult for a reverse engineer to get to the key. That means you could assemble it in such a way that no complete piece of it can be found in the binary. But still if someone attaches a debugger at runtime she could still read it out of a variable trivially. In the end it remains an arms race between you and the reverse engineer.